# Removing coordinates from GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers

I have this MultiPoint in GeoJSON format:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[20.564356201588417,51.931611083447535],[20.535517090260296,51.806113553165176],[20.236139648854046,51.76703620941208],[20.13314282268217,51.8706019711191]]},"properties":{"id":1}}
```

I want to use the getClosestPoint () function after clicking on a point to delete it. How to remove coordinates of this point from GeoJSON?

Answer (score 1):

You could work with the geometry.

1. Get the closest point `pto` using [getClosestPoint](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_MultiPolygon-MultiPolygon.html#getClosestPoint)
2. Get the coordinates `coords` of the geometry using [getCoordinates](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_MultiPolygon-MultiPolygon.html#getCoordinates)
3. Iterate the coordinates and remove the one you obtain in step 1, just compare the values of the coordinates `pto[0] === coords[i][j][k][0] && pto[1] === coords[i][j][k][1]`, where `j,k,i` are the indexes to traverse `coords` (just as an example)

BTW I am assuming you [read](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#readFeature) the feature from geojson to object